# Java RMI : How to transfer non-remote existing object class

Tags: java, rmi, jira-rest-java-api

I wanted to transfer the Issue class from [jira rest client api](https://www.baeldung.com/jira-rest-api,), and apparently this class is not serializable.

Here  my code :

**rmi_server side**

`JiraConnection.class`

```java
public interface JiraConnection extends Remote {
    ...
    public List<Issue> getIssuesFromJqlSearch(String jqlSearch) throws RemoteException, TimeoutException;
    ...
}
```

`JiraServant.class`

```java
public class JiraServant extends UnicastRemoteObject implements JiraConnection {
    private String username = "...";
    private String password = "...";
    private String jiraUrl = "...";
    private JiraRestClient restClient;

    public JiraServant() throws RemoteException {
        super();
        this.restClient = getJiraRestClient();
    }
    ....
    private JiraRestClient getJiraRestClient() throws RemoteException {
        return new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory()
                .createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(this.jiraUrl , this.username, this.password);
    }
    public List<Issue> getIssuesFromJqlSearch(String jqlSearch) throws RemoteException, TimeoutException {
        try {
            final SearchResult searchResult = getJiraRestClient().getSearchClient()
                    .searchJql(jqlSearch)
                    .get(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return Lists.newArrayList(searchResult.getIssues());
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.err.println("jira rest client timeout from jql search error. cause: " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("jira rest client get issue from jql search error. cause: " + e.getMessage());
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

`Main.class`

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("=== RMI Server ===");
        try{
            JiraServant servant  =  new JiraServant();
            String url = "rmi://localhost:5097/jira-api";
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(5097);
            Naming.rebind(url, servant);

            System.out.println("Server ready...");
        }catch(RemoteException | MalformedURLException e){
            System.out.println("Failed to open the server");
        }

    }
}
```

**rmi_client side**

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("=== === RMI Client === ===");
        try{
            String url = "rmi://localhost:5097/jira-api"; //todo: change this to jira

            JiraConnection jiraConnection = (JiraConnection)  Naming.lookup(url);
            String jqlSearch = "project = 'SDR' AND assignee = 627cba6c6ba8640069cf1faa AND status IN (Open) ORDER BY created DESC";

            try {
                List<Issue> results = jiraConnection.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(jqlSearch);
                
                for(Issue issue: results){
                    String reporterAccountId = Objects.requireNonNull(issue.getReporter()).getAccountId();
                    System.out.print("Reporter: "+ jiraConnection.getUser(reporterAccountId));
                    System.out.println(", Key: "+issue.getKey() + ", Title: "+issue.getSummary() + ", Status: " + issue.getStatus().getName());
                }
                System.out.println("Ben a "+results.size() +" open issues");
            } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }catch(RemoteException | MalformedURLException e){
            System.out.println("Failed to open the server");
            System.out.println("Error Message : "+e);
        } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; 
nested exception is: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; 
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue
```

Does anyone have solution to allow me to transfer Issue class from server to client, using RMI.

Comment: where is your [mcve]?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I added my code sample,

Comment: If it isn't `Serializable` and you can't make it so, you will have to send something else instead and map it at both ends.

Comment: @user207421 I didn't think that was my only solution, but I'd say it's the only one.

Comment: @lordyhas Eh? You didn''t think so but now you do? If you have access to the source code you could use `writeReplace()` and `readResolve()`, but then if you had access to the source code you could make it `Serializable`.

Comment: @user207421  I wanted to say that I was already thinking of such a solution but I was hoping to find other alternatives by coming here. I didn't think it was the only one.
So I used the `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1` (Gson) package from google to map the `Issue` class.
Thanks for your help.